# QGIS 3.14 GDAL ERROR

Tags: qgis, windows

I installed the new version of QGIS, QGIS 3.14 and I am having problems in running GDAL algorithms through Processing.
For instance "clip raster by mask layer" always gives me:

```
Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/../AppData/Local/Temp/processing_CBxlhD/70b11f1d802a45ffafcfad0804ef2610/OUTPUT.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Investigating more the LOG, I have this error:

```
ERROR 1: Failed to identify source layer from datasource.
```

How to solve it?

Comment: what is your input layer?

Comment: My inputs are a raster file and a polygon shapefile. I did with SAGA (Clip raster with polygon) and it works. I do not understand why GDAL is given me errors.

Comment: If you created the polygon as a new shapefile layer in QGIS, be sure to turn off editing mode before clipping.